All controllers return NOT_FOUND after Micronaut 4 migration
I am currently trying to migrate an azure function (@HttpTrigger) from Micronaut 3 (3.10.4) to Micronaut 4 (4.6.3 to be precise). I have been using their official migration guide here and I think I added/updated all the required dependencies.
To be more concrete:

I updated the micronaut-parent to the .platform location with the previously mentioned version
Jdk and release version were already set to 17
Added snakeyaml dependency
Added micronaut-serde-jackson dependency and the path to annotationProcessorPaths
javax dependencies were already updated to jakarta

When I try to start the Micronaut application with IntelliJ I seems to start up successfully:

but when I try to reach any of the endpoints defined in my @Controller classes a NOT_FOUND is always returned, this behavior is consistent in the test suite, all @MicronautTest classes fail because the function is returning NOT_FOUND. I also do not see any of the custom log lines defined in the various @Get methods in the console
This is what the test results look like:

This is what the @HttpTrigger class looks like:
public class Function extends AzureHttpFunction {

    @FunctionName("HttpTrigger")
    public HttpResponseMessage invoke(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.GET }, route = "{*route}",
            authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        
        context.getLogger().fine("Http trigger uri " + request.getUri());
        ThreadContext.put("id", context.getInvocationId());
        
        return super.route(request, context);
    }
}

From what I can tell based on the example micronaut gives themselves this should also be okay still for version 4.6.3
And finally here is my POM file with some internal dependencies removed:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>eab-function</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.platform</groupId>
        <version>4.6.3</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <micronaut.version>4.6.3</micronaut.version>
        <jdk.version>17</jdk.version>
        <release.version>17</release.version>
        <exec.mainClass>my.group.id.Function</exec.mainClass>
        <functionAppName>eab</functionAppName>
        <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
        <micronaut.runtime>azure_function</micronaut.runtime>
        <junit-platform.version>5.11.3</junit-platform.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.34</lombok.version>
        <log4j.version>2.24.1</log4j.version>
        <checkstyle.plugin.version>3.6.0</checkstyle.plugin.version>
        <checkstyle.config.version>1.0.0</checkstyle.config.version>
        <jacoco.plugin.version>0.8.12</jacoco.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    <!-- exclude StaticLoggerBinder.java from being added to jar file to avoid warning conflict.
                                    This class is runtime provided by logback classic-->
                                    <exclude>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.micronaut.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.16.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resourceGroup>FAKE-rg</resourceGroup>
                    <region>westeurope</region>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>17</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE</name>
                            <value>1</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>host.json</include>
                                        <!-- <include>local.settings.json</include> -->
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>azure-functions-java-library</excludeArtifactIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-serde-processor</artifactId>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=my.group.id</arg>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=eab-function</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        @{argLine}
                        --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                    </argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-rxjava2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-rxjava2-http-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-azure-function-http</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20240303</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.12</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-azure-function-http-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
            <artifactId>system-lambda</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-serde-jackson</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-azure-function</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

EDIT 1:
Per request from a comment here is a full debug log in text for one of the failing tests: https://pastebin.com/Ku6HBa11 (new link because the old one got removed somehow)

Provide the error details in text format.

@PravallikaKV I have added a pastebin link with a debug log and the error in text

There might have been changes in how routes are being handled or configured. Check if the controllers are correctly annotated and endpoints are mapped properly.

Ensure that your @Controller is defined with the correct path.
Check if @Get, @Post annotations are specified with correct paths.

Use updated POM.XML as below:
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>io.micronaut.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1</version>
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <jdk.version>21</jdk.version>
    <release.version>21</release.version>
    <micronaut.version>4.7.1</micronaut.version>
    <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    <micronaut.aot.enabled>false</micronaut.aot.enabled>
    <micronaut.aot.packageName>com.example.aot.generated</micronaut.aot.packageName>
    <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.36.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
    <functionAppName>default</functionAppName>
    <functionResourceGroup>java-functions-group</functionResourceGroup>
    <functionAppRegion>westus</functionAppRegion>
    <functionRuntimeOs>windows</functionRuntimeOs>
    <functionRuntimeJavaVersion>17</functionRuntimeJavaVersion>
    <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
    <exec.mainClass>com.example.Application</exec.mainClass>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-azure-function</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-azure-function-http</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-serde-jackson</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-azure-function-http-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <configFile>aot-${packaging}.properties</configFile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <java>
              <licenseHeader>
                  <file>${project.basedir}/LICENSEHEADER</file>
              </licenseHeader>
          </java>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
          <resourceGroup>${functionResourceGroup}</resourceGroup>
          <appServicePlanName>java-functions-app-service-plan</appServicePlanName>
          <region>${functionAppRegion}</region>
          <runtime>
            <os>${functionRuntimeOs}</os>
            <javaVersion>${functionRuntimeJavaVersion}</javaVersion>
          </runtime>
          <appSettings>
            <property>
              <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
              <value>~4</value>
            </property>
          </appSettings>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>package-functions</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
              <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
              <excludeArtifactIds>azure-functions-java-library</excludeArtifactIds>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>

          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.core.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-serde-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.serialization.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.example</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=demo</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

Function.java:
@FunctionName("ExampleTrigger")
    public HttpResponseMessage invoke(
            @HttpTrigger(
                name = "req",
                methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
                route = "{*route}",
                authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
                HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
                final ExecutionContext context) {
        return super.route(request, context);

DefaultController:

package com.example;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.serde.annotation.Serdeable;

@Controller("/default")
public class DefaultController {

    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Get
    public String index() {
        return "Example Response";
    }

    @Post
    public SampleReturnMessage postMethod(@Body SampleInputMessage inputMessage){
      SampleReturnMessage retMessage = new SampleReturnMessage();
      retMessage.setReturnMessage("Hello " + inputMessage.getName() + ", thank you for sending the message");
      return retMessage;
    }
}

@Serdeable
class SampleInputMessage{
    private String name;

    public SampleInputMessage() {
    }

    public SampleInputMessage(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Serdeable
class SampleReturnMessage{
    private String returnMessage;
    public String getReturnMessage() {
        return returnMessage;
    }
    public void setReturnMessage(String returnMessage) {
        this.returnMessage = returnMessage;
    }
}

Test the function:
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
//logs
[INFO] ---------------------< example.micronaut:default >----------------------
[INFO] Building default 0.1
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- enforcer:3.5.0:enforce (micronaut-enforce) @ default ---
[INFO] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.version.RequireJavaVersion passed
[INFO] Rule 1: io.micronaut.maven.enforcer.CheckSnakeYaml passed
[INFO]
[INFO] --- mn:4.6.3:generate-import-factory (default-generate-import-factory) @ default ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mn:4.6.3:generate-openapi-generic (default-generate-openapi-generic) @ default ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mn:4.6.3:generate-openapi-client (default-generate-openapi-client) @ default ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- mn:4.6.3:generate-openapi-server (default-generate-openapi-server) @ default ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ default ---
[INFO] Copying 2 resources from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) @ default ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ default ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\uname\Downloads\micronaut-azure-http-functions-maven-java\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.13.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ default ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- mn:4.6.3:start-testresources-service (default-start-testresources-service) @ default ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:3.4.0:test (default-test) @ default ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running example.micronaut.DefaultFunctionTest
17:50:45.538 [main] INFO
  //logs
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.542 s -- in example.micronaut.DefaultTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.784 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-11-25T17:50:47+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


It indeed seems like Micronaut is no longer automatically prefixing /api to the controller classes so there was a mismatch between the available routes and the routes used by the @Client in the test classes, will do some more testing today and post my own answer with all the changes that were required. Thanks!
